# git2go: Listing files with the latest committer and commit date

Tags: git, go, libgit2

I'm attempting to use git2go to output a list of files, along with their latest author and most recent commit date in a repository. Looping through the files with `tree.Walk` seems to be straightforward:

```
package main

import (
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/libgit2/git2go.v25"
)

// FileItem contains enough file information to build list
type FileItem struct {
    AbsoluteFilename string    `json:"absolute_filename"`
    Filename         string    `json:"filename"`
    Path             string    `json:"path"`
    Author           string    `json:"author"`
    Time             time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
}

func check(err error) {
    // ...
}

func getFiles(path string) (files []FileItem) {

    repository, err := git.OpenRepository(path)
    check(err)

    head, err := repository.Head()
    check(err)

    headCommit, err := repository.LookupCommit(head.Target())
    check(err)

    tree, err := headCommit.Tree()
    check(err)

    err = tree.Walk(func(td string, te *git.TreeEntry) int {

        if te.Type == git.ObjectBlob {

            files = append(files, FileItem{
                Filename: te.Name,
                Path:     td,
                Author:   "Joey",     // should be last committer
                Time:     time.Now(), // should be last commit time

            })

        }
        return 0
    })
    check(err)

    return
}
```

What I can't work out is, which approach do I take? Can I, inside the function passed to `tree.Walk`, work out the commit based on the limited information of the `git.TreeEntry`? Or do I need to separately construct a list of commits along with associated files and somehow cross-reference them?

Comment: Would revwalk help? [walking history](http://ben.straub.cc/2013/10/02/revwalk/)

Comment: That looks promising thanks Mark, I'll investigate properly in the morning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [log example](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/ex/HEAD/log.html) shows how to filter revwalk by path. It involves diffing each commit to it's parent with the path as a pathspec argument. It's not trivial.